# How to continue apt setup in shell if you choose to show the config update diff

Tags: linux, debian, ubuntu, shell, apt

I have updated from shell as usual, but during the setup at 90% a package that has update the config file asked me to enter one of the following options

```
Yes(Y) No(N) Show the diff (D)
```

I have entered *D* to show the differences, the problem is that now the shell remained on the Diff  screen, and if I click enter on keyboard it goes to end of the diff screen and I don't know how to confirm and continue the installation.

[image: show diff during update screen]

What should I do?
Is there some special shortcut to continue in these situations?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`q` should quit the `less` process which displays the difference. Then you can know where are the differences and choose between the old version and the new. If you keep your own version, the new version is however available (with a `.dpkg-dist` suffix) and permit you to merge manually both files. (If you use the new file, a backup of the configuration is available with the `.dpkg-old` suffix).